# Differentiation of piecewise multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} xy & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 
1 & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$

Is it correct to say that for all $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, $f_x (x,y) = y$?

Comment: Well, the correct way should be to use the definition by limit since you have a piecewise function. That is,  to find $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}$.

Comment: @user1027216 I know that. I specifically wants to know whether it is correct to say the statement in the question.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Your comment is an actual answer... You should post it as such.

Comment: @user1027216 The fact that the function is defined in branches does not automatically mean that you cannot use the usual differentiation rules. You can use the rules in this case because when $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ you always have a small horizontal segment centered in $(x,y)$ where the expression for $f$ is $xy$.

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, that was the reason why I didn't say what "that is not correct". However, I was sure that the definition we can use. Thank you very much for the feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct. For every $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ there is a whole *neighbourhood* of $(x,y)$ not containing $(0,0)$, on which your function is identical to $f(x,y)=xy$. The partial derivative is a local property, i.e. it is unaffected by changes of the function outside an arbitrary small neighbourhood, so $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xy)=y$ for any point $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$.

Obviously, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)\mid_{(x,y)=(0,0)}$ does not exist